# How to lock bottom sheet to his peek height?

Tags: android

I am using this library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

And i did this bottom sheet but after some actions i want to lock it on the bottom of the screen only with 1 raw visible. 
[This](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031) is the tutorial where I am looking from. I want to lock the bottom sheet like the 3rd item from the tutorial.

If you have any ideas will be great :)

Here is my code:

```
private void initBottomSheet() {
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: so you mean that you want to show only 1 item visible out of 3 available items?

Comment: I mean i want to expend it and after i did my work want to collapse it to its peek height position and lock it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have forgotten to use this code : `mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);`

Comment: no I am not, and this cant help, this method is only for how much from the bottomsheet can see if it is collapsed

Comment: I putted it, now you can see it